# Can I apply [Required] attribute dynamically to ASP.NET MVC ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

depending on configuration at each site, some fields on a form may or may not be required. Can I apply the [Required] attribute to fields of my ViewModel in code? I'd like to take advantage of all the conveniences of form validation, but I can't hard-code the [Required] attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). It could be used as a replacement of Data Annotations and has great integration with [ASP.NET MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation). It allows you to define dynamic validation rules based on runtime conditions.

Answer (score 0):

No.*  Metadata is cooked into the assembly.

*(Well I guess you could emit the assembly at runtime but lord that would be alot of crazy work)